# Poké Ball only shakes once and the Pokémon is caught

Tags: pokemon-x-y

Sometimes when I throw a Poké Ball at a Pokémon in Pokémon X/Y, instead of the ball shaking three times, it shakes once and then the Pokémon is caught. What is happening here?

I haven't actually played Pokémon since Generation 3 (and I don't ever recall this happening), so is this maybe something from Gen 4/5? Or new in Gen 6?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Nevermind, I've obviously silly at looking things up. Looks like it's called "critical catching" and that this isn't a bug or anything.

It's new since Generation 5 (and appears in Generation 6). There's a slight chance where the ball will only shake on the ground once before capture.

[Source](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Critical_catch#Critical_capture)

Comment: The more Pokémon you've caught, the higher the chance of it happening. Also, a critical catch is not guaranteed to succeed, it just greatly improves your chances of catching the Pokémon.

Comment: @Nolonar Is there a source for your first point? Sounds interesting

Comment: http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Critical_catch#Critical_capture

Comment: Yeah, the benefit of a critical capture is that you only need to pass the capture check once, instead of four times.

Answer (score 5):

It's called a *critical capture*.  This was introduced in Generation V and is documented in Generation VI on a sign hidden behind a Cut tree to the left of the entrance to Reflection Cave on Route 11:

> #### Trainer Tips!
>
> When catching a Pokémon, sometimes the Poké Ball you throw will rock only once.  This is called a "critical capture," and the more Pokémon you catch, the more likely it will occur.

For technical information, see [this Bulbapedia article](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Catch_rate#Critical_capture).