# What do the streaming stars mean when catching Pokémon?

Tags: pokemon-go

When catching Pokémon now, there will occasionally be streaming stars that come off of the poke ball after a successful catch.

This appears to be something that was added in an update, but I don't know what it means.

Comment: @Jerry true albeit the answers to that question are oudated (at least from the context of this question it looks that way). With that being said, I'm not sure exactly what the outcome of the meta experiment regarding poke-go questions that are almost dupes but the answers/questions differ slightly from the original question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe what you are seeing is the [Critical Capture Animation](https://www.reddit.com/r/TheSilphRoad/comments/5urh2v/critical_catch_animation/):

You can read more about critical captures in [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/136738/163757).

Comment: Thank you! I was wondering if it had to do with the various medal catch bonuses, and that appears to be the case.